# SELECT with calculated column that is dependent upon a correlation

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I don't do a lot of SQL,and most of the time, I'm doing CRUD operations.  Occasionally I'll get something a bit more complicated.  So, this question may be a newbie question, but I'm ready.  I've just been trying to figure this out for hours, and it's been no use.

So, Imagine the following table structure:

```
> | ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | .. | Col8 |
```

I want to select ID and a calculated column.  The calculated column has a range of 0 - 8 and it contains the number of matches to the query.  I also want to restrict the result set to only include rows that have a certain number of matches.

So, from this sample data:

```
> | 1 | 'a' | 'b' | 1 | 2 |  
> | 2 | 'b' | 'c' | 1 | 2 |  
> | 3 | 'b' | 'c' | 4 | 5 |  
> | 4 | 'x' | 'x' | 9 | 9 |
```

I want to query on Col1 = 'a' OR Col2 = 'c' OR Col3 = 1 OR Col4 = 5 where the calculated result > 1 and have the result set look like:

```
> | ID | Cal |
> | 1  |  2  |
> | 2  |  2  |
> | 3  |  2  |
```

I'm using T-SQL and SQL Server 2005, if it matters, and I can't change the DB Schema.

I'd also prefer to keep it as one self-contained query and not have to create a stored procedure or temporary table.

Comment: Try this: SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Col1='a' OR Col2='c' OR Col3=1 OR Col4=5) AND (COUNT(Col1) > 1 OR COUNT(Col2) > 1 OR COUNT(Col3) > 1 OR COUNT(Col4) > 1) GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4

Not tested...

Comment: Can you explain your results table?

Comment: Why, in your example, does your resultset for Id=3 have a calculated column total of 3?  Looks like it should be 2.

Comment: @jro that would make sense to me

Comment: Oops, I'll clean up the results to be accurate and add the column names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer will work with SQL 2005, using a CTE to clean up the derived table a little.

```
WITH Matches AS
(
    SELECT ID, CASE WHEN Col1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN Col2 = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN Col3 = 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN Col4 = 5  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Result
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Col1 = 'a' OR Col2 = 'c' OR Col3 = 1 OR Col4 = 5 
)
SELECT ID, Result
FROM Matches
WHERE Result > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that leverages the fact that a boolean comparison returns the integers 1 or 0:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, (Col1='a') + (Col2='c') + (Col3=1) + (Col4=5) AS calculated
  FROM MyTable
) q
WHERE calculated > 1;
```

Note that you have to parenthesize the boolean comparisons because `+` has higher precedence than `=`.  Also, you have to put it all in a subquery because you normally can't use a column alias in a `WHERE` clause of the same query.

It might seem like you should also use a `WHERE` clause in the subquery to restrict its rows, but in all likelihood you're going to end up with a full table scan anyway so it's probably not a big win.  On the other hand, if you expect that such a restriction would *greatly* reduce the number of rows in the subquery result, then it'd be worthwhile.

---

Re Quassnoi's comment, if you can't treat boolean expressions as integer values, there should be a way to map boolean conditions to integers, even if it's a bit verbose.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, 
      CASE WHEN Col1='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN Col2='c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    + CASE WHEN Col3=1   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN Col4=5   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS calculated
  FROM MyTable
) q
WHERE calculated > 1;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could avoid the subquery at the cost of repeating the same `(Col1='a') + (Col2='c') + ...` in the `WHERE` clause, which SQL Server should optimize away (making the longer query the only cost)

Comment: This will work in `MySQL` but not in `SQL Server`, it cannot cast booleans to integers.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple: Yes, I was thinking of the same point and I was adding the last paragraph in the answer above as you were writing your comment.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Really?  How inconvenient.  Well one can use `CASE` or something.  I'll edit the answer to show an example.

Comment: I get the error Incorrect syntax near '=' and it references the line with the boolean values. What am I missing?

Comment: In SQL Server, I couldn't get this to execute - "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'" - I'm guessing it doesn't like the column alias

Comment: Thanks to Quassnoi for adding a table alias for my derived tables.  That should help.

Answer (score 1):

This query is more index friendly:

```
SELECT  id, SUM(match)
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, 1 AS match
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   col1 = 'a'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, 1 AS match
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   col2 = 'c'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, 1 AS match
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   col3 = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, 1 AS match
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   col4 = 5
        ) q
GROUP BY
        id
HAVING  SUM(match) > 1
```

This will only be efficient if *all* the columns you are searching for are, first, indexed and, second, have high cardinality (many distinct values).

See this article in my blog for performance details:

- [**Matching 3 of 4**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/17/matching-3-of-4/)

Comment: The problem with this is that it means you have to do index seeks for every item you filter on and it assumes that id is a clustered PK.  If one of these isn't indexed, you end up doing a table scan plus index seeks (worst case 4 table scans).  This is going to be suboptimal, where a single table scan would do.

Comment: `@Strommy`: you're right, and that's exactly what the post says. But if the columns are selective, this solution can be optimal.

Comment: @Quassnoi:  I agree with you.  Both work and yours has the possibility of being much faster assuming index coverage.  There's more than one way to skin a cat, I guess...